# how to correctly move a sprite with the keys avoiding conflicts in pygame?

Tags: sprite

Is a simple game where a monkey throws bananas.

I want to launch the banana when the space bar is released and continue running.
When the space bar is held the banana must remain attached to the monkey until the space bar is released.
The first launch works properly, from the second onwards the bananas are not thrown correctly.

```
    done=False
    while not done:
        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == QUIT:
                done = True
            if ev.type ==KEYDOWN:
                if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                    move_right=True
                if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                    move_left = True
                if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                    space_down=True
                    still=True
            elif ev.type ==KEYUP:
                if ev.key== K_RIGHT:
                    move_right=False
                if ev.key== K_LEFT:
                    move_left=False
                if ev.key==K_SPACE:
                    still=False
                    space_down=False
                    launch=True
    
    
    
    #Game logic
        #move monkey
        if move_right and monkey.rect.right<screen.get_width():
            monkey.rect.x += 5
        elif move_left and monkey.rect.left>0:
            monkey.rect.x -= 5
    
        #banana launch
        if space_down:
            banana=Throw_Objects()
            banana.rect.midtop = monkey.rect.topright
            space_down=False
        if still and not space_down and move_right and monkey.rect.right < screen.get_width():
            banana.rect.x += 5
        if still and not space_down and move_left and monkey.rect.left > 0:
            banana.rect.x -= 5
    
        if launch:
            for banana in all_object:
                banana.rect.y -= 5
                if banana.rect.top < 0:
                    banana.kill()
```

Any suggestions to make sure that the banana is launched when the space bar is released and when, as long as you press the space bar, the new banana will remain attached to the monkey without affecting the movement of the previous one?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolded by adding a sprite group after launch in this way

```
if space_down:
    banana=Throw_Objects()
    banana.rect.midtop = monkey.rect.topright
    space_down=False


if move_right and monkey.rect.right<screen.get_width():
    monkey.rect.x += 5
    if still:
        banana.rect.x += 5

elif move_left and monkey.rect.left>0:
    monkey.rect.x -= 5
    if still:
        banana.rect.x -= 5

if launch :
    banana.rect.y -= 5
    only_banana.add(banana)
    launch=False

for banana in only_banana:
    banana.rect.y -= 5

for banana in all_object:
    if banana.rect.top < 0:
        banana.kill()
```